# Vuex default store in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

my app is in vue.js, now I want to rewrite it in nuxt.js, I have also vuex store in my app, for nuxt.js, vuex store syntax is different, is there any way to use my default store in nuxt.js without changing it? thanks and sorry for my English :))

Answer (score 0):

It's not different. You don't change it significantly.

All you have to do is put it into separate js file and a little rewrite:

```
export const state = () => {

  return {
    cart: [],
    other_variables:{},
  }
}

export const mutations = {
// put all mutations here
}
```

name it index.js and put it into "store" folder. That's it. Just use it as before. Easy.

Comment: Thanks, but in the components, when I want to get actions or getters, this syntax couses error, ...mapActions(["fetchProjects", "getNextProjectPage"]),  and nuxt requers this syntax, ...mapActions({fetchProjects: 'projects/fetchProjects'})

Comment: unfortunately I can not comment on errors of your code without seeing it. I had no problem converting my app from vuejs to nuxtjs with the store model I provided

Answer (score 0):

```
// ./store/global.js OR you can use any name for js file 
export const state = () => ({
  loader: false,
})

export const mutations = {
  setLoader(state, bool) {
    state.loader = bool
  },
}

export const getters = {
  getLoader: state => state.loader,
}

// get variable from store
computed: {
  loader(){ return this.$store.getters['global/getLoader'] },
}

// set value for loader
this.$store.commit('global/setLoader', true)

// for example if you will work in other store files ./store/requests.js and you need to change loader value you can use this code
export const actions = {
  someRequest({commit, state, dispatch}){
    this.commit('global/setLoader', true)
    setTimeout(() => {
     this.commit('global/setLoader', false)
    }, 2000)
  },
}
```

Comment: Could you include an explanation of your answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).